# Detect when resize event is triggered by the Android browser's on screen keyboard

Tags: javascript, android

I have a form that uses the resize event to keep the layout proportional to the size of the browser viewport. The problem I am having is that the event fires when the on screen keyboard appears on the Android browser. This causes the layout of the form to change so the input field moves after the browser focuses on it. This makes my application unusable on Android. This is not an issue with IOS as the on screen keyboard appears to be an overlay that doesn't fire the resize event.

Is there a way to detect that the resize event was raised by the appearance of the keyboard?

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195278/preventing-viewport-resize-of-web-page-when-android-soft-keyboard-is-active>

Answer (score 2):

Ok , this is fix for html5 (browser) app .

```
var isKeyboardOpen = false;

// Override onresize event if you have it already just insert code 
// also you can check id of element or any other parameters
if (document.activeElement.tagName == "INPUT" ||
    document.activeElement.tagName == "input") {

    // regular onresize
    // Indicate normal resize

}
else {
    // We know that element who opens keyboard is in 'focus'
    // avoid resize
}

// To check is it keyboard open use this code 

window.addEventListener('native.showkeyboard', keyboardShowHandler);

window.addEventListener('native.hidekeyboard', keyboardHideHandler);

function keyboardShowHandler(e){
    isKeyboardOpen = true; //always know status
}

function keyboardHideHandler(e){
    isKeyboardOpen = false;
}
```

Initially try to prevent by setting the flag :

```
var object = document.getElementById("IwillOpenKeyboardOnMobile");
object.addEventListener("focus", ONFOCUSELEMENT);

function ONFOCUSELEMENT() {
    isKeyboardOpen = true; 
}

// opposite event is blur
```