# Bottom Fixed div getting pushed up with android keyboard

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a fixed div at the bottom, but in response view, in android, it gets pushed up with the keyboard.

```
const ContactBackgroundImage = styled.div`
  color: white
  padding: 50px
  height: 118px
  position: fixed
  bottom: 0
  left: 0
  right: 2px
  text-align: left
  background-position: top
  background-repeat: no-repeat
  background-image: url('/Images/background.png');
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    background-position: left top
  }
`;
```

And then my div is rendering this.

```
<ContactBackgroundImage/>
```

When the app is in a responsive mode in android phone the keyboard pushes the div up. i want the div to stay there at the bottom of kayboard
[image]

Comment: That's how phones and their keyboards work.

Comment: @NikolaLukic it is with position: fixed;

Comment: @cloned so you are saying that there is no way to fix it? but in ios it works perfecrt.. the fixed div gets hidden behind the kayboard

Comment: This is a webpage right?

Comment: @Examath Yes. Its a web app build in react.js. i am just trying to view it inmobile browner and only in android the div gets pushed on top

Comment: Sorry , here is how to detect it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338497/detect-when-resize-event-is-triggered-by-the-android-browsers-on-screen-keyboar/50370316#50370316

Answer (score 0):

// Wanted do add comment but not enough reputation, so i'll post it as answer and delete if it's wrong.

Have you tried setting z-index for your div? Maybe it's on the same layer with android keyboard and so gets pushed.

Comment: I mean. setting index has nothing to do with this. The keyboard pushed the whole div up..

Comment: actually i gave a thought to the z-index thing you said. I tried to give my form div `z-index: 100` and the ContactBackgroundImage div `z-index: -1`.. it works but the links inside my ContactBackgroundImage dosent work anymore. and my ContactBackgroundImage div only goes behind the form div if i give -1 zindex

Comment: Can you post screenshot of how it looks?

Comment: added image above

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem some time ago, rather than using `position:fixed` use `position:absolute` or `position:relative` and also try `top:100%` with positions.

```css
const ContactBackgroundImage = styled.div'
  color: white
  padding: 50px
  height: 118px
  position: absolute
  bottom:0
  left: 0
  right: 2px
  text-align: left
  background-position: top
  background-repeat: no-repeat
  background-image: url('/Images/background.png');
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    background-position: left top
  }
`;
```

Comment: Still the same :( in android phone the keyboard pushes it up

Comment: So, i have fixed the problem. Used `position: fixed` and what I did is, when the hight of the div is less then 480px (means when the keyboard is on the screen) i gave the div index of -1 `z-index: -1` and it just hides behind the div above

Comment: `position:fixed` will move along, can you please try with position absolute ?